# How to link spatial and non spatial table in geoserver

Tags: geoserver, spatial-database, fields-attributes, table

I have a vector data published in GeoServer. I have other two non-spatial table which can be linked to the vector by a common field name. Now I would like to know how this can be done using GeoServer?I had read something regarding views in GeoServer.Will the views helps in linking this?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a view in the database and then have GeoServer use that as the basis for a layer. It works [almost exactly](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/postgis.html#publishing-a-postgis-view) like a table would.